# Microphone grabs game audio and "mixes" it with my voice drowning it out. no speakers, using headset

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, games, microphone

Using 20.04 and it seems it started to happen recently. I have no speakers so the game sound should not have been picked up via the microphone. But if I use mumble or record while playing the game sound is mixed with my voice. It is also higher volume so it drowns me out.

I'd like the microphone just to pick what I say to it, not what is generated by the system...

Comment: what type of microphone do you use? (usb, xlr, ...)

Comment: it's a dual jack, for in/out. plugged at the back of the desktop it started happening recently